# How can i use the amazon kindle version 4 with debian squeeze?

Tags: debian-squeeze, kindle

Hello i am using the amazon kindle version 4. To synchronize my e-books with this device i can use calibre in version 0.8.33 with my opensuse 12.1 box which works fine. However the version shipped with the current debian squeeze release is too old and does not support the kindle 4.

Trying to install it from source does not work because of missing dependencies. Is there any other way of getting calibre other than using the testing wheezy release ?

**Update:**

Now that i have solved the problem of installing i am not able to charge the kindle. when i plug in the cable the display switches over and states that the device is not charging. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question. Fortunately i came up with the idea to search for calibre in sourceforge and i found a precompiled version of calibre including the needed libraries here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/calibre/files/0.8.41/calibre-0.8.41-i686.tar.bz2/download
As user Unpack this with:

```
mkdir calibre && mv calibre-0.8.41-i686.tar.bz2
cd calibre
tar xvfj calibre.0.8.41-i686.tar.bz2
mv calibre-0.8.41-i686.tar.bz2 ../
```

As root copy the calibre directory to */usr/local/share* and change the permissions to root:root

```
cp -r calibre /usr/local/share/
chown -R root:root /usr/local/share/calibre
```

Now link the calibre binary to */usr/local/bin*

```
ln -s /usr/local/share/calibre/calibre /usr/local/bin/calibre
```

Hope i could help people having the same problem.